# Unable to Select option from dropdown using JavascrtptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Can anyone provide me a failsafe(ish) method for selecting text from dropdowns on this page I am practicing on?

https://www.club18-30.com/club18-30

Specifically, the 'from' and 'to' airport dropdowns.  I am using the following code:

```
   public void selectWhereFrom(String query, String whereFromSelect) throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement dropDownContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath(departureAirportLocator));
    dropDownContainer.click();

    selectOption(query,whereFromSelect);
}

public void selectOption(String query, String option) {
    String script =
            "function selectOption(s) {\r\n" +
                    "   var sel = document.querySelector(' " + query + "');\r\n" +
                    "   for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++)\r\n" +
                    "   {\r\n" +
                    "       if (sel.options[i].text.indexOf(s) > -1)\r\n" +
                    "       {\r\n" +
                    "           sel.options[i].selected = true;\r\n" +
                    "           break;\r\n" +
                    "       }\r\n" +
                    "   }\r\n" +
                    "}\r\n" +
                    "return selectOption('" + option + "');";

    javaScriptExecutor(script);
}
```

This seems to successfully populate the box with text but when I hit 'Search' I then receive a message saying I need to select an option, suggesting it has not registered the selection?

I would rather avoid JavaScriptExecutor but haven't been able to make these Selects work with a regular Selenium Select mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a function for each dropdown, one for setting the departure airport and another for setting the destination airport. I've tested the code below and it works.

The functions

```
public static void setDepartureAirport(String airport)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.departureAirport div.departurePoint")).click();
    String xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'departurePoint')]//ul//li[contains(@class, 'custom-select-option') and contains(text(), '"
            + airport + "')]";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}

public static void setDestinationAirport(String airport)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.destinationAirport div.airportSelect")).click();
    String xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'destinationAirport')]//ul//li[contains(@class, 'custom-select-option') and contains(text(), '"
            + airport + "')]";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

and you call them like

```
driver.get("https://www.club18-30.com/club18-30");
setDepartureAirport("(MAN)");
setDestinationAirport("(IBZ)");
```

I would suggest that you use the 3-letter airport codes for your search, e.g. "(MAN)" for Manchester. That will be unique to each airport but you can use any unique part of the text.